# How do I keep my Python program from using too much memory on my SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

I have a script that scans a network drive and finds csv files it then cleans and inputs into a SQL database. I do this with a python script that pulls the csv into a pandas dataframe and then I use the to_sql command with a SQLAlchemy engine object that connects using a 64-bit ODBC connection.

This program is multi-threaded, so each folder containing the csv files opens a new thread. There may be 9 threads going at a time depending on when it runs.

My issue is, this program uses a lot of memory while it is running, and the memory does not go down once it is done running. Since this script runs multiple times a day, the RAM usage will eventually max out and slow the server down even with a query that would normally be very fast.

Is there any way to optimize my program so that the memory goes down once the program is done running? Is this something that needs to be done on the SQL server? I just need to know which might be causing the issue. Below is a sample of the code I'm using.

The rest of the code is really just cleaning the data, and it works quickly. The last thing is the number of rows being inserted by each csv is up to 10,000. The database is currently sitting at 2 billions rows. I know it's a lot of rows, and I understand this will use a lot of memory, but why does the memory go up while it is running, stay there once it is done running, and then build onto that during the next run? I have indexing that allows reasonable queries to pull quickly, and those indexes are responsible for the RAM usage, but I'm not sure why it always just builds onto itself.

Below is the basics of the code I'm using.

```
engine=create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://Username:Password@DatabaseName")

def function(file_path):
    csv_files = os.listdir(file_path)
    for row in csv_files:
        shot_df.to_sql(name='table_name', con = engine, 
        if_exists='append', index=false)


    
for row in folders_with_csv_files:
    file_path = row
    t = threading.Thread(target=function, args=(file_path, ))
    t.start()
```

Comment: How are you acomplishing "multithreading"?  What process hosts the python code?  Is it on the same server as SQL Server?  Is it the Python host or the SQL Server using the memory?  How much memory?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer the first 2 questions, but I hope the code I posted can give some insight into how I'm running multiple threads. As for the process hosting the python code, I am using task scheduler to run my python script. The script is running on the SQL server, though I have the same problem if I run it from my local computer. The SQL Server process is what is using the memory, and it caps out at 96% memory. I increased the server to 128 GB just to test and it will use 96% of that.

Comment: Ok, so then this is expected behavior of SQL Server.  If you don't want SQL Server to use all your server memory you can limit it in the instance configuration.  See linked question.

Comment: Alright, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the threads are truly done running, they should be garbage collected and memory will go down. I am guessing that there may be zombie processes / threads that are still hanging around.

Using `ps aux | grep <something that wouldidentify your process>` or a tool like activity monitor sorted by memory usage will help you find those and kill them. If you share a toy version of the script that creates the threads maybe we can also discern why those threads aren't finishing.

EDIT: after you included the method that the thread calls I think the issue is that you are opening connections to your db and not closing them. You can close these connections after they are used.

Comment: I added some code to my post for the loop calling the threads.

Comment: ah! I think the issue is that you are opening up lots of connections to your database and never closing them. To solve -- either open one connection you pass around, close the connection after you use it, or set up a connection pool.